# What is difference in JSF between component.getAttributeName() vs. component.getAttributes().get("name")

Tags: jsf-2, components

What is difference in JSF between

```
UIComponent component;
component.get *AttributeName*()  and
component.getAttributes().get("attibute name")
```

?

```
component.set *AttributeName*(value) 
component.getAttributes().put("attibute name", value)
```

?

Make it any difference if I for example set `disabled=true` attribute in invoke phase in `getAttributes()` HashMap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, it doesn't make any difference. Technically, `UIComponent#getAttributes()` allows the developer to not worry about the exact component type while getting/setting the attributes.

Look at your particular example with `disabled="true"`. The `UIComponent` superclass doesn't have any `isDisabled()` method at all. You'd need to perform an `instanceof` check on e.g. `HtmlInputText` before you can cast it and finally invoke `isDisabled()` on it. The `getAttributes()` is then much easier in order to be independent from that. A lot of `UIComponent` related methods in standard JSF API take or return `UIComponent` superclass instead of a specific type.

In properly designed components, both delegate under the covers ultimately to the same, the `UIComponent#getStateHelper()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you explain in some words what `UIComponent#getStateHelper()` are used for ?

Comment: To save component's state across postback requests on the same view. Component instances are essentially request scoped. See also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+getstatehelper and http://balusc.blogspot.com/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html